# field_view_field()

Tags: 8, theming

I'm new to Drupal 8 and Twig and I can't figure out what the equivlent of 
field_view_field is? So lets say I did this in Drupal 7 within a template file:

```
print render(field_view_field('node', $node, 'body', array(
    'type' => 'text_summary_or_trimmed',
    'label' => 'hidden',
)));
```

How would I output a custom field in drupal 8 template?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The php equivalent in drupal 8 is:

```
$build = $node->body->view('view_mode');
$output = \Drupal::service('renderer')->renderRoot($build);
```

In twig you don't need to render yourself, twig does this for you. So you can simply put the first line in a preprocess function:

```
function theme_preprocess_hook(&$variables) {
   $variables['body123'] = $node->body->view('view_mode');
}
```

and output in twig:

```
{{ body123 }}
```

Edit: I see you are using a field formatter, not a view mode, and use the preloaded node, so this is the preprocess for a node template:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
       $variables['body123'] = $variables['node']->body->view(array('type' => 'text_summary_or_trimmed'));
}
```

Put this in the `mytheme.theme` file in the theme root directory.

More information is available in the [change record](https://www.drupal.org/node/2208327).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the rpely, I'm getting a 'Fatal error: Call to a member function view() on null' however when I try to use it from my theme file

Comment: Got rid of that error I was putting it in bartiksub_preprocess_page but now not getting anything back

Comment: There's a small bug in the preprocess code (magic `$node` var). If it's like D7 you should find that in `$variables['node']`

Comment: You have the load $node first. If you use the node that is preloaded, then you can use `$variables['node']` in preprocess.

Comment: Hi, thanks, I'm not totally following, so you mean I need to do: theme_preprocess_hook($node, &$variables) ?

Comment: You did not mention it, is your twig a node template? Then you have to put a `mytheme_preprocess_node(&$variables)` in `your mytheme.theme` file in the root directory of your theme. In a node preprocess function the node is preloaded in `$variables['node'] and you can use the last code example in my answer.

Comment: Hi yeah it's node template. Ok cool I will try that tomorrow! Thanks for your help